# CNN-LSTM with TimeDistributed Layers behaving weirdly when trying to use tf.keras.utils.plot_model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a CNN-LSTM that looks as follows;

```
SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 32
BATCH_SIZE = 32
EPOCHS = 30
n_filters = 64
n_kernel = 1
n_subsequences = 4
n_steps = 8

def DNN_Model(X_train):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(TimeDistributed(
        Conv1D(filters=n_filters, kernel_size=n_kernel, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_subsequences, n_steps, X_train.shape[3]))))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=n_filters, kernel_size=n_kernel, activation='relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
    model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    return model
```

I'm using this CNN-LSTM for a multivariate time series forecasting problem. the CNN-LSTM input data comes in the 4D format: [samples, subsequences, timesteps, features]. For some reason, I need `TimeDistributed` Layers; or I get errors like `ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 4, 8, 35]`. I think this has to do with the fact that `Conv1D` is officially not meant for time series, so to preserve time-series data shape we need to use a wrapper layer like `TimeDistributed`. I don't really mind using TimeDistributed layers - They're wrappers and if they make my model work I am happy. However, when I try to visualize my model with

```
    file = 'CNN_LSTM_Visualization.png'
    tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file=file, show_layer_names=False, show_shapes=False)
```

The resulting visualization only shows the `Sequential()`:

[image]

I suspect this has to do with the TimeDistributed layers and the model not being built yet. I cannot call `model.summary()` either - it throws `ValueError: This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling` build()`or calling`fit()`with some data, or specify an`input_shape `argument in the first layer(s) for automatic build` Which is strange because I *have* specified the input_shape, albeit in the `Conv1D` layer and not in the `TimeDistributed` wrapper.

I would like a working model together with a working `tf.keras.utils.plot_model` function. Any explanation as to why I need TimeDistributed and why it makes the plot_model function behave weirdly would be greatly awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your input layer at the beginning. Try this

```
def DNN_Model(X_train):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(n_subsequences, n_steps, X_train)))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(
        Conv1D(filters=n_filters, kernel_size=n_kernel,
               activation='relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=n_filters,
              kernel_size=n_kernel, activation='relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)))
    ....
```

Now, you can plot and get a summary properly.

```
DNN_Model(3).summary() # OK 
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(DNN_Model(3)) # OK
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using an `Input` layer is to simply pass the `input_shape` to the `TimeDistributed` wrapper, and not the `Conv1D` layer:

```py
def DNN_Model(X_train):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(TimeDistributed(
        Conv1D(filters=n_filters, kernel_size=n_kernel, activation='relu'), input_shape=(n_subsequences, n_steps, X_train.shape[3])))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=n_filters, kernel_size=n_kernel, activation='relu')))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
    model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    return model
```